# Make the freeze line in Google Sheets invisible

Tags: google-sheets

When I freeze some rows in Google Sheets, a grey line appears to indicate where the frozen rows are. Is it possible to make this line invisible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. I'm afraid not. It does so by design.

It is the only way one can tell that rows/columns are frozen.
It is also used as a handle for changing the frozen range.

[image]